# Vue3 use ref from third party package in setup script

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, ref, vue-script-setup

I'm using Vue 3 for my project and need to get use a ref from a third-party ReCaptcha package during the submission of a form. The code does not recognize the ref name since I did not personally
create this ref:

```
async function submitContact() {
  const token = await mrecaptcha.getToken();
...

'mrecaptcha' is not defined.
```

It's used in the template like this:

```
<recaptcha v-if="isClient" ref="mrecaptcha" :site-key="siteKey" />
```

Usage can be found in the docs for this package here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@appsbd/vue3-recaptcha

Comment: Do you use composition API or options API?

Comment: composition API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `ref` in the `script` to get the element reference of `recaptcha`.

```
const mrecaptcha = ref(null)
```

Ex:

```
<script setup>
const mrecaptcha = ref(null)

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(mrecaptcha)
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought initializing it myself would treat it as an entirely new ref item and I would lose its properties like .getToken(); But it seems to work  I'll mark this as answer when it allows me to